# SQL single query to fetch next 12 dates for a given input date

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I want a single query to fetch next 12 dates (first day of month) for a given date.

For example, input date is 01/01/2019 (DD/MM/YYYY) then the output should be as below:

[image: output]

I have tried to run a loop using the `DATEADD` function as:

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 0
while(@i<12)
BEGIN
SELECT DATEADD(mm, @i, '01/01/2019');
SET @i = @i+1
END
```

This works but is there a way I can fetch the required output with a single query?

Comment: which Rdbms are you using?

Comment: to state the hopefully obvious, doing this in an application language would be a better use of appropriate tools.

Comment: @Rams since mysql does not have a dateadd() function, only a date_add(), the code in the question is for ms sql server. Removed the mysql tag.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for SQL Server

```
with cte(DateVal) as(
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2019/01/01')  dt
union all
select  DATEADD(day,1,dateval) from cte where DateVal<DATEADD(day,11,'2019/01/01') )
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2017:

```
;with cte as (
  select cast('01/01/2019' as date) as DT, 1 as Id
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, DT) as DT, Id + 1 as Id
  from cte where Id < 12
)
select format(DT, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as DT from cte;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/78996

Answer (score -1):

With MariaDB and their [Sequence Storage Engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2019','%d/%m/%Y') + seq DAY FROM seq_0_to_11
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=b460903763ae564bbc1bee3b54364ff8)